# Как получить сообщение от TCP сервера в нескольких частях программы java

Tags: java

Мне необходимо получать сообщения от сервера:

- Сообщение по запросу клиента
- Сообщение которое просто отправил сервер (уведомление)

Я получаю сообщение:

```
BufferedReader answer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
String massage = answer.readLine();
```

Как я могу это реализовать? Где я могу об этом почитать ?

Comment: Найдите книгу Head first "Изучаем Java" (https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/7821666/) там как раз разбиратеся данный вопрос.

Comment: Для начало вам надо прочитать про [Сокеты](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/654-klassih-socket-i-serversocket-ili-allo-server-tih-menja-slihshishjh) Вот тут [пример](https://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/java-socket-client-examples-tcp-ip) как реализовать клиент-сервер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Методы обратного вызова](https://www.fandroid.info/primery-metodov-obratnogo-vyzova-callbacks/) - то, что вам нужно. в основном классе создаете TCP клиента и интерфейс для делегатов. Другие классы подписываются на получения событий от основного класса и обрабатывают действия в методах обратного вызова, когда основной класс их вызовет.

Вот пример моей реализации TCP клиента:

```
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TcpClient {
    public interface TcpClientDelegate {
        void ConnectionStatus(TcpStatus status);

        void DataReceive(String message, byte[] data);

        void SocketError(String message);
    }


    public enum TcpStatus {
        Connection,
        Connected,
        Disconected
    }


    private class OutBuffer {
        public byte[] buffer = new byte[0];
        public String str_buffer = "";

        public void AddToBuff(byte[] tmp_buff, String tmp_string) {
            byte[] r = new byte[buffer.length + tmp_buff.length];
            System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, r, 0, buffer.length);
            System.arraycopy(tmp_buff, 0, r, buffer.length, tmp_buff.length);
            buffer = r;
            str_buffer += tmp_string;
        }

        public void ClearBuff() {
            buffer = new byte[0];
            str_buffer = "";
        }
    }


    private List<TcpClientDelegate> listDelegate = new ArrayList<>();

    private Thread threadSocket;
    private Thread threadCommunication;

    private Socket socket;
    private OutputStream outStream;
    private InputStream inStream;

    private byte[] bufferData = new byte[1024];
    private OutBuffer bufferReceive = new OutBuffer();
    private int bytesToRead = 0;
    private ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream =
            new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);

    public String serverHost;
    public int serverPort;

    public boolean clientConnected = false;

    private String LOG_TAG = "TCP_CLIENT";

    public TcpClient() {
    }

    public TcpClient(TcpClientDelegate delegate, String host, int port) {
        subscribeDelegate(delegate);
        serverHost = host;
        serverPort = port;
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        SocketStop();
        super.finalize();
    }


    public void subscribeDelegate(TcpClientDelegate delegate) {
        if (!listDelegate.contains(delegate)) {
            listDelegate.add(delegate);
        }
    }

    public void unsubscribeDelegate(TcpClientDelegate delegate) {
        if (listDelegate.contains(delegate)) {
            listDelegate.remove(delegate);
        }
    }

    private void callConnectionStatus(TcpStatus status) {
        for (TcpClientDelegate delegate : listDelegate) {
            delegate.ConnectionStatus(status);
        }
    }

    private void callDataReceive(String message, byte[] data) {
        for (TcpClientDelegate delegate : listDelegate) {
            delegate.DataReceive(message, data);
        }
    }

    private void callSocketError(String message) {
        for (TcpClientDelegate delegate : listDelegate) {
            delegate.SocketError(message);
        }
    }


    public void Start(String host, int port) {
        try {
            if (clientConnected) SocketStop();
            //Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Start socket");
            serverHost = host;
            serverPort = port;
            callConnectionStatus(TcpStatus.Connection);

            threadSocket = new Thread(new TcpClient.ClientThread());
            threadSocket.start();
            bufferReceive.ClearBuff();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //Log.e(LOG_TAG, ex.getMessage());
        }
    }


    public void SocketStop() {
        try {
            if (outStream != null) {
                outStream.close();
                //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "outStream kill");
            }
            if (inStream != null) {
                inStream.close();
                //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "inStream kill");
            }
            if (socket != null) {
                try {
                    socket.shutdownInput();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, ex.getMessage());
                }
                try {
                    socket.shutdownOutput();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, ex.getMessage());
                }
                socket.close();
                //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "socket exp. kill");
            }
            if (threadCommunication != null) {
                threadCommunication.interrupt();
                // Log.d(LOG_TAG, "communication thread kill");
            }
            if (threadSocket != null) {
                threadSocket.interrupt();
                //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "socket thread kill");
            }
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Socket stopping ok!");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Stop finally");
            threadCommunication = null;
            threadSocket = null;
            outStream = null;
            inStream = null;
            socket = null;
            clientConnected = false;
            bytesToRead = 0;
            callConnectionStatus(TcpStatus.Disconected);
        }
    }


    public void Send(final String sData) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (clientConnected && socket != null && outStream != null) {
                    try {
                        final String sendData = sData;
                        outStream.write(sendData.getBytes(), 0, sendData.getBytes().length);
                        outStream.flush();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        //Log.e(LOG_TAG, ex.getMessage());
                        callSocketError(ex.getMessage());
                        SocketStop();
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        //Log.e(LOG_TAG, ex.getMessage());
                        callSocketError(ex.getMessage());
                        SocketStop();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public void Send(final byte[] sData) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (clientConnected && socket != null && outStream != null) {
                    try {
                        final byte[] sendData = sData;
                        outStream.write(sendData, 0, sendData.length);
                        outStream.flush();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        //Log.e(LOG_TAG, ex.getMessage());
                        callSocketError(ex.getMessage());
                        SocketStop();
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        //Log.e(LOG_TAG, ex.getMessage());
                        callSocketError(ex.getMessage());
                        SocketStop();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }


    class ClientThread implements Runnable {


        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverHost);
                SocketAddress endpoint = new InetSocketAddress(serverAddr, serverPort);
                socket = new Socket();
                socket.connect(endpoint, 1500);
                threadCommunication = new Thread(new TcpClient.CommunicationThread());
                threadCommunication.start();
                clientConnected = true;
                callConnectionStatus(TcpStatus.Connected);
            } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
                callSocketError(ex.getMessage());
                SocketStop();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                callSocketError(ex.getMessage());
                SocketStop();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                callSocketError(ex.getMessage());
                SocketStop();
            }
        }
    }

    class CommunicationThread implements Runnable {


        public CommunicationThread() {
            try {
                if (inStream != null) {
                    inStream.close();
                }
                inStream = socket.getInputStream();
                if (outStream != null) {
                    outStream.close();
                }
                outStream = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                //Log.e(LOG_TAG, ex.getMessage());
                callSocketError(ex.getMessage());
                SocketStop();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, ex.getMessage());
                callSocketError(ex.getMessage());
                SocketStop();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                String streamDataString;
                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && bytesToRead != -1 && clientConnected) {
                    bytesToRead = inStream.read(bufferData);
                    //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "reads bytes : " + bytesToRead);
                    //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "available with reads: " + inStream.available());
                    if (bytesToRead < 0) {
                        SocketStop();
                        break;
                    }
                    if (bytesToRead > 0) {
                        byteArrayOutputStream.reset();
                        byteArrayOutputStream.write(bufferData, 0, bytesToRead);
                        streamDataString = byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8");
                        bufferReceive.AddToBuff(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), streamDataString);
                        if (inStream.available() <= 0) {
                            // Log.d(LOG_TAG, "available: " + inStream.available());
                            callDataReceive(bufferReceive.str_buffer, bufferReceive.buffer);
                            bufferReceive.ClearBuff();
                        }

                    }
                }
            } catch (SocketException ex) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "msg 8" + ex.getMessage() + "----------");
                ex.printStackTrace();
                SocketStop();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "msg 9" + ex.getMessage());
                ex.printStackTrace();
                SocketStop();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "msg 10" + ex.getMessage());
                ex.printStackTrace();
                SocketStop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Пример использования внутри активити:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TcpClient.TcpClientDelegate {

    TcpClient tcpClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tcpClient = new TcpClient();
        tcpClient.subscribeDelegate(this);
        tcpClient.Start("192.168.1.45", 30000);
    }

    @Override
    public void ConnectionStatus(TcpClient.TcpStatus status) {

        Log.d("TcpClientDelegate", "TCP Client status " + status.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void DataReceive(String message, byte[] data) {
        Log.d("TcpClientDelegate", "TCP Client receive " + message);
    }

    @Override
    public void SocketError(String message) {
        Log.d("TcpClientDelegate", "TCP Client error: " + message);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(tcpClient.clientConnected){
            tcpClient.Send("hello");
        }
    }
}
```